# Unexpected behavior around recursive regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-recursion

I am trying to match C++ argument type which can contain balanced `<`and `>` characters.

With this regex:
`(\<(?>[^<>]|(?R))*\>)`

On this string: `QMap<QgsFeatureId, QPair<QMap<Something, Complex> >>`

It matches all expect the first 4 characters (QMap).

Now, if I add `\w+` at the start of my regex, it now only matches the end of it (`QPair<QMap<Something, Complex> >>`) and not the whole string.

What is the explanation and how to solve this?

You can try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/0jqrvZ/1).

This is intented to use in Perl 5.10+ (5.24).

Comment: What is the expected result you need to get in the end? `QMap` as Group 1 and `<QgsFeatureId, QPair<QMfap<Something, Complex> >>` as Group 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`(?R)` construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) recurses the *entire* pattern. When you add `\w+` at the start, it is also accounted for when the recursion takes place. However, what you want to recurse is the Group 1 subpattern.

You need a [*subroutine call*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) that will recurse the capturing group subpattern:

```
(\w+)(<(?:[^<>]++|(?2))*>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ns7T0g/3)

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing the identifier (you may change it to `[a-zA-Z]\w*`)
- `(<(?:[^<>]++|(?2))*>)` - Group 2 (that will be recursed)

  - `<` - a literal `<`
  - `(?:[^<>]++|(?2))*` - either 1+ chars other than `<` and `>` (possessively, to make it faster) or (`|`) the whole Group 2 pattern (`(?2)`).
  - `>` - a literal `>`

Results:

```
Match:   QMap<QgsFeatureId, QPair<QMfap<Something, Complex> >>
Group 1: QMap
Group 2: <QgsFeatureId, QPair<QMfap<Something, Complex> >>
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for the details. Btw, would be nice to add tagg regex-recursive, which I can't do due to my low rank.

Comment: Welll, maybe it is a good idea. Something like `regex-recursion` or `regex-recursive`.